# Upgrade to Wordpress 4.7.2 Issue

Tags: wordpress

I have just upgraded to Wordpress 4.7.2 from 4.3.x, and I am now experiencing an issue whereby going to example.com continues to redirect to example.com/blog.

We are currently using the Unbounce Plugin where we host all of our pages on Unbounce, except for example.com/blog. All other Unbounce pages are functioning as per normal.

We also use Redirection, for which I had a redirect set up for example.com -> example.com/blog, when the AWS servers went down a few days ago.

Would anyone know why this is? I will continue to edit as I investigate.

Comment: Have you cleared your web browser cache?

Comment: I always thought cmd+shift+r cleared cache (hard refresh), I guess not! 

Looks like it's working as intended now after clearing the cache. Thanks!